# Why is my 3 month old dwarven baby severely cave adapted?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

From the wiki article, [cave adaptation](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Cave_adaptation) is suppose to take a long time, up to two years. However, my 3 month old dwarf baby is already severely cave adapted and vomiting a ton. I also have an outdoor meeting area which I'm fairly sure he and his mother spend a lot of time in.

How is it possible that the baby (but not his mother) is severely cave adapted, despite spending lots of time outdoors?

[image]

Comment: Maybe dwarves sometimes have long gestation cycles and he was in a cave  for almost two years prior to being born...

Comment: You're probably better off reporting this as a bug on the DF bug tracker, it's clearly not intended behavior regardless of the cause.

Comment: @Namfuak Where is the bug tracker?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/mantisbt/my_view_page.php

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug that was solved on version 40.22, and it could be related to your issue:

- [0008655](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/mantisbt/view.php?id=8655) - *Babies get cave adaptation quickly.*
- [0008431](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/mantisbt/view.php?id=8431) - <del>*Dwarven babies born with cave adaption*</del>. Closed as duplicated of [0008655](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/mantisbt/view.php?id=8655).

If your issue persists, it should be better to double-check if it is the case of reopen the issue or report a new one.